# Not able to hit a specific Get method ...Error 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("all")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllCompetitions()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Repository.FindAll());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetCompetition")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCompetitionById(long id)
    {
        Competition competition = Repository.FindById(id);
        if (competition == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, competition);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("format")]
    public HttpResponseMessage format(string postedFormat)
    {
        CompetitionMediaFormat format = (CompetitionMediaFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(CompetitionMediaFormat), postedFormat, true);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Repository.FindByFormat(format));
    }
```

I am able to hit the first two get methods but when i hit "format" method am getting a 404 Not found error

**Client App call**

var response = await client.GetAsync("api/Competition/format/music");

**Route Config**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please let me know where am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the name of the parameter 'postedFormat', it will not match with your route paramter name 'id'.  Try adding a route that specifies postedFormat as the last parameter.

Comment: thanks it works now!! Didnt knew we had to give the parameter name of HttpGet methods as "id" always.....have too many methods, cant add a route for every method!!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be as @Justin Harvey, suggested. i.e to make you method

from this

```
public HttpResponseMessage format(string postedFormat)
{...}
```

to

```
public HttpResponseMessage format(string id)
{...}
```

this is because the default route : `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",` accepts an `id`.

You can change your route to accept postedFormat as input parameter.